# Wait for button action on TkInter

Tags: python, button, tkinter

Hi guys im trying to make a subprogram that waits for a button to be pressed in order to continue, in othe words: a loop that has a condidtinal, beeing the conditianal having a button pressed, and I have no idea of what can i use to do that.

Comment: Every `button` has a `command` parameter where you can pass a function object.

Comment: What you ask really isn't how GUI programming works. If the button is in a popup dialog that's one thing, but to have some sort of loop waiting for a button press doesn't make sense. That's what the mainloop already does -- wait for events. Can you describe a bit more what you want to accomplish, and what you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy example of what others have said, this function waits until you hit the button, when it will run the function written:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('waiting for button click...')

def carry_on:
    # do what ever

button = tk.Button(text = 'click to continue', command = carry_on)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

if you have a more specific question please add more information :)